# How can I smoothly scroll the page to top in this AngularJS application with virtual page items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making a small **Contacts application** with Bootstrap 4 and **AngularJS v1.6.6**.

The application simply displays an *Users* JSON. Since the JSON returns a large number of users, the application also has a pagination feature.

```js
// Create an Angular module named "contactsApp"
var app = angular.module("contactsApp", []);

// Create controller for the "contactsApp" module
app.controller("contactsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=100&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture";
  $scope.contactList = [];
  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var oldList = $scope.contactList || [];
    $scope.contactList = $filter('filter')($scope.contacts, $scope.search);
    if (oldList.length != $scope.contactList.length) {
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
    };
    $scope.itemsCount = $scope.contactList.length;
    $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
  };

  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // contacts arary
      $scope.contacts = data.data.results;
      $scope.filterList();

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 24;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.filterList();

      $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
        $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
        $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
      };

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

    });
}]);

$('.pagination li a').on('click', function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.site-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.grid {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.grid .item {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid .text {
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

.grid a {
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.grid .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.grid .thumbnail {
  padding: 15px;
}

.grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>


<div data-ng-app="contactsApp">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
    <div class="grid" ng-if="contactList.length > 0">
      <div data-ng-repeat="contact in contactList | limitTo : perPage : startAt" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img ng-src="{{contact.picture.large}}" class="rounded-circle"></div>
          <div class="text">
            <h2 class="card-title text-center">
              {{contact.name.first }} {{contact.name.last }}
            </h2>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 text-center">
              <li class="text-muted">Lives in {{contact.location.city}}</li>
              <li><a href="mailto:{{contact.email | lowercase}}">{{contact.email | lowercase}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="tel:{{contact.cell}}"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="pl-2">Call</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p ng-if="contactList.length <= 0" class="text-center">There are no contacts</p>
    <div ng-if="pageMax > 1">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="prevPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(pageMax) track by $index" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[$index == pageNum - 1]">
          <a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="currentPage($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="nextPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

With the pagination items being created *problematically*, inside the controller, the small piece of jQuery code intended to *smoothly scroll the page to top* when an item is clicked, does *not* work.

What is a viable alternative?

Comment: You should place your jquery code in such a way that it is executed after the DOM is rendered. In your code your pagination class element is in ng-if, chances are high that when your jquery code is 'scanned' while attaching events that element might not exists.

Comment: @MukeshVerma Yes, I know *what* I should do, but I do not know *how* to do it. Uing `$(window).load()` does not work either.

Comment: A hacky way would be, since your ng-if is governed by pageMax variable so whenever you are setting $scope.pageMax , immediately after that put your jquery code after some time interval. This will make sure once the DOM is refreshed after setting pageMax your element will be available and you can attach events. If you can create codeopen it will be easy to communicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Create an Angular module named "contactsApp"
var app = angular.module("contactsApp", []);

// Create controller for the "contactsApp" module
app.controller("contactsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", "$timeout", function($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout) {
  var url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=100&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture";
  $scope.contactList = [];
  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var oldList = $scope.contactList || [];
    $scope.contactList = $filter('filter')($scope.contacts, $scope.search);
    if (oldList.length != $scope.contactList.length) {
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
    };
    $scope.itemsCount = $scope.contactList.length;
    $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
  };

  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // contacts arary
      $scope.contacts = data.data.results;
      $scope.filterList();

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 24;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.filterList();

      $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 300);
        $timeout( function(){
            $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
            $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
        },0);
      };

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };
    });
}]);

$('.pagination li a').on('click', function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.site-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.grid {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.grid .item {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid .text {
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

.grid a {
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.grid .card-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.grid .thumbnail {
  padding: 15px;
}

.grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="contactsApp">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
    <div class="grid" ng-if="contactList.length > 0">
      <div data-ng-repeat="contact in contactList | limitTo : perPage : startAt" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img ng-src="{{contact.picture.large}}" class="rounded-circle"></div>
          <div class="text">
            <h2 class="card-title text-center">
              {{contact.name.first }} {{contact.name.last }}
            </h2>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 text-center">
              <li class="text-muted">Lives in {{contact.location.city}}</li>
              <li><a href="mailto:{{contact.email | lowercase}}">{{contact.email | lowercase}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="tel:{{contact.cell}}"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="pl-2">Call</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p ng-if="contactList.length < 1" class="text-center">There are no contacts</p>
    <div ng-if="pageMax > 1">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="prevPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(pageMax) track by $index" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[$index == pageNum - 1]">
          <a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="currentPage($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="page-link" ng-click="nextPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I injected $timeout and updated `$scope.currentPage` function.
You can read document at [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to understand $timeout feature